# objective-c novice - convert IBOutlet code to code in main

Tags: cocoa, command

I'm trying to get this code which runs when a button on GUI is clicked to run in the main function of a command line app (no GUI). This works when a button is clicked:

```
-(IBAction)WriteAdu:(id)sender{
    char* command = "mk15";
    char* serialNumber = "A09208";
    ADUWrite(1, command, serialNumber);
}
```

There is also this:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    ADUInit();
    NSLog(@"inited");
}
```

When I try to put everything into the main function of a different program it doesn't seem to work. It doesn't have any errors, it just doesn't work:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    ADUInit();
    ADUWrite(1,"mk00", NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Is there something that application did finish launching does that I need to do in a command line app?

Comment: `ADUInit();` is missing from the main function and seems vital.

Comment: oops was there and it's there now and it makes no difference.

Comment: It does have something to do with ADUInit(). when ADUInit() is in WriteAdu() I get the same result as in the command line program.

Comment: I just read here: http://ontrak.net/cocoa.htm that ADUInit() initializes a driver. why do I have to init a driver in applicationDidFinishLaunching and not in writeADU or in main. is there and equivalent of applicationDidFinishLaunching in a command line program?

Comment: the driver has to be initialized at startup of the app, and if once initialized usually doesn't need to repeat that. So it is done when the app finishes launching. It should also work in main, I assume your example doesn't work since main returns immediately and thus closes the connection to your hardware.